# Python .replace usage for (parentheses) and some error mistake

Tags: python, sqlite

Latest problem:

```
   iterator = p.finditer(s)
NameError: name 's' is not defined
```

how to solve it ?

I am writting a function that I preferred that after I selected command in sqlite3 database. I could change my words in (parentheses)

I have written some python for .replace but it seems not working in my function.
Could anyone check my error Thank you.

This is my function without adding .replace()

```
def readciscodevice(function, device):
            conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
            cur = conn.cursor()
            if device == "switch":
                    cur.execute(
                            "SELECT DISTINCT command FROM switch WHERE   function =? or function='configure terminal' or function='enable'  ORDER BY key ASC",
                            (function,))
                    read = cur.fetchall()
                    return read
            elif device == "router":
                    cur.execute(
                            "SELECT DISTINCT command FROM router WHERE   function =? or function='configure terminal' or function='enable'  ORDER BY key ASC",
                            (function,))
                    read = cur.fetchall()
                    return read;
            elif device == "showcommand":
                cur.execute(
                        "SELECT DISTINCT command FROM showcommand WHERE   function =? or  function='enable'  ORDER BY key ASC",
                        (function,))
                read = cur.fetchall()
                return read;



    a = input("function:")
    b = input("device:")
    p = re.compile('\(.*?\)')
iterator = p.finditer(s)
for match in iterator:
    s = s[:match.start()] + [match.start():match.end()].replace(match.group(), dict[match.group()]) + s[match.end()]
        for result in readciscodevice(a,b):
                print(result[0])
```

now I add my .replace into the last of my function(some error exist...)

```
a = input("function:")
            b = input("device:")
 for match in iterator:
        s = s[:match.start()] + [match.start():match.end()].replace(match.group(), dict[match.group()]) + s[match.end()]
            for result in readciscodevice(a,b):
                    print(result[0])
            iterator = p.finditer(s)

error:`:match.end()` ---SyntaxError: invalid syntax
error:`.replace`---statement expected, found Py:RBRACKET Statement expected, found Py:DOT ,unsolved reference 'replace'
```

Before function output:

```
interface fa(fanumber)/(fanumber)
ip adress (ip) (subnet mask)
```

My expected output that I want to replace my parameter into(parentheses):

```
interface fa0/1
ip adress 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0
```

Could anyone can help me to fix some bugs and my replace problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.you misses a `s`

```
s = s[:match.start()] + s[match.start():match.end()].replace(match.group(), dict[match.group()]) + s[match.end()]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I could run my program now but there were a error . Could u help me about     iterator = p.finditer(s)
NameError: name 's' is not defined

Comment: `iterator = p.finditer(s)` in this line what you are expecting as `s` ?